# Running Scalar Valued SQL functions in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I am wondering how one can run a scalar SQL function in python. I have a function that will "clean" a given string (ie. removing special characters/extra spaces, etc.). The current method I use is the following

def cleanup(df):

```
server87= """
    DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};
    SERVER={};
    DATABASE={};
    Trusted_Connection=yes;
    """.format("server-87", "test_prod")

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(server87)
curr = cnxn.cursor()
cnxn.execute("""create table #tmp_std_file (
                    row_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
                    name varchar(max)
                )"""
            )

names = df['NAMES'].to_list()              
curr.executemany("""INSERT INTO #tmp_std_file
            VALUES (test_prod.dbo.name_cleanup(?))""",
            map(lambda x: [x], names),
    )
curr.commit()
rows = cnxn.execute("SELECT name FROM #tmp_std_file ORDER BY row_id")
lisrows = [row.name for row in rows]
return lisrows
```

I pass the dataframe and it returns 'lisrows' which is the cleaned up names. My question is is there a faster way to do this? I feel like writing to a table and executing and then reading that table takes a long time.

Comment: `curr.fast_executemany = True` might speed up the insert somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

build a csv file then use sql loader to upload the csv file in batch